# What can I do to stress test a new USB harddrive?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, usb-drive

I'm running ubuntu desktop 14.04.

I bought a 2TB USB3 seagate harddrive, but after a week it started producing I/O errors and I was unable to recover any data (I lost quite a lot).

So, now I have a replacement 2TB and I'm slightly hesitant to start loading all my data on it again, so I have been looking around for tools to stress test the drive.. But all I come across are general hardware performance tests.

Can anyone recommend some tools to test this drive out to see if it's likely to fail again? I'd quite like to run a stress test over a period of hours or even days before I start using it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benchmarking the disk with `dd`, `hdparm` or similar tools won't neccesarily tell you if the disk is defective. Have you considered to run a SMART self-test on the disk?

The following command will start a self-test on the specified disk:

```
smartctl -t long /dev/sdX
```

The following command will show you the current status (if the test is still running) and the result (if the test is completed):

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdX
```

Of course, this will only tell you if the disk is defective *right now*, and is no guarantee that it won't fail at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

> dd if=/dev/zero of=/mountpoint_of_drive/testfile bs=4096 count=7864320

Writes a 30G file to your disk.  You can fiddle with the blocksize and count to get the file writes that you want.

Other commands to look into would be

> hdparm -t /dev/diskID (test results for buffered disk reads)
>
> hdparm --direct -t /dev/diskID (unbuffered disk reads)

blktrace & blkparse are really good tools to use too.  I think they are standard on CENTOS but should be available for ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest [iometer](http://www.iometer.org/doc/downloads.html) - I use it for benchmarking, but it should do a reasonable job of exercising your disk.

Comment: iometer is 404'd. Its home page no longer delivers the binaries http://sourceforge.net/projects/iometer/files/iometer-stable/1.1.0/iometer-1.1.0-linux.x86_64-bin.tar.bz2/download